# wordpress hard coded contact form failing

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I decided to hard code a contact form for my Wordpress blog. I created a template and it is as follows. I just can't see the issue with it despite taking some time to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I haven't forgotten to sanitise input. I'll add that function when i see the issue here.  Thanks in advance...

Incidentally, I get this message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in F:\xampp\htdocs\new_theme\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve_child\contact.php on line 54

```
<?php /* Template Name: contact */?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submitted"])){

  if($_POST["contactName"] === ""){
    $nameError = "Please enter your name.";
    $hasError = true;
   } 

  else $name = $_POST['contactName'];
if($_POST["email"] === ""){
    $emailError = "Please enter your email address.";
    $hasError = true;
  } 

  else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i",  $_POST['email'])) {
    $emailError = "You entered an invalid email address.";
    $hasError = true;
} 

else $email = $_POST['email'];

if($_POST['comments'] === ""){
    $commentError = "Please enter a message.";
    $hasError = true;
}

else $comments = $_POST["comments"];
```

}

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = "mathornley@gmail.com";
    $subject = "From Android Scoop - From: $name";
    $body = "Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Comments: $comments";
    $headers = "From: $name <$emailTo> \n Reply-To: $email";

    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
```

?>

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true){ ?>
        <div class="thanks">
      <p>Thanks, your email was sent successfully.</p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php else{?>
      <?php if(isset($hasError){?> <p class="error">Sorry, an error occured.<p>

          <div class="form_left">       
    <form action="<?php the_permalink();?>" method="post">
        <label><span class="requiring">*</span>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contactName"/>
        <?php if($nameError)?> <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>

                <label><span class="requiring">*</span>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
        <?php if($emailError)?><span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>

        <label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone"/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send your message"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_right">        
      <label><span class="requiring">*</span>Message:</label>
      <textarea name="comments" rows="20" cols="30" class="required requiredField"></textarea>
         <?php if($commentError)?><span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span>
</form>
            </div>

<?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntax errors:

```
<?php }else{
        if(isset($hasError)){?>
```

1,

```
<?php } ?>

<?php else{?>
```

You can't close the PHP tags, then open it again starting with `else` when using brackets. If you use alternative if/then statements, then this is possible

2,

`if(isset($hasError)`

You're missing the closing parenthesis on the if statement

Full:

```
<?php
if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true){
    echo '<div class="thanks"><p>Thanks, your email was sent successfully.</p></div>';
}else{
    if(isset($hasError)){?>
        <p class="error">Sorry, an error occured.<p>
          <div class="form_left">       
            <form action="<?php the_permalink();?>" method="post">
                <label><span class="requiring">*</span>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="contactName"/>
                <?php if($nameError)?> <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>

                        <label><span class="requiring">*</span>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
                <?php if($emailError)?><span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>

                <label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Send your message"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
            </div>

            <div class="form_right">        
              <label><span class="requiring">*</span>Message:</label>
              <textarea name="comments" rows="20" cols="30" class="required requiredField"></textarea>
                 <?php if($commentError)?><span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span>
        </form>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Sure, but you can't start a php tag with `else{` this only works with alternative if statements like: `else:`

Comment: Ah ok. I just checked and used that snippet which renders the page as though a comment has been submitted

Comment: Thanks for the advice Samuel. I'm still newish to PHP and appreciate your efforts. Sorted it now!. Very first if statement, where 'submitted' is checked, closed too early, just before wp_mail function if statement.